# Replace the line above a matched pattern

Tags: regex, shell, awk, sed

I have a html file which has a table in it as follows:

`<td>unknown</td>
<td>blah11</td>
...
<td>unknown</td>
<td>blah24</td>
...`

I need to match on 'blah24' and replace the 'unknown' above with 'test' to give:

`<td>test</td>
<td>blah24</td>`

I have tried to research sed & awk solutions but have only been able to find either 'inserts before the matched pattern' or 'replace after the matched pattern'.

I only have basic shell tools available on a stand alone machine using cygwin.

Comment: It you use `tac`, it prints the file backwards, you can then use the "replace next line trick", use as `tac file | awk ..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sed you could do

```
sed -n '/blah24/{x;s/unknown/test/;x};x;1!p;${x;p}' file

<td>unknown</td>
<td>blah11</td>
...
<td>test</td>
<td>blah24</td>
...
```

Every line it exchanges the current line for the hold buffer. If it finds blah24, then it exchanges the held line, changes it to test, then swaps it back. It prints for every line except 1(as it would print a blank space).

Comment: I found this sed command with Ed Morton's inclusion of the -i option to do the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'NR>1{if(/blah24/) sub(/unknown/,"test",prev); print prev} {prev=$0} END{print prev}' file
<td>unknown</td>
<td>blah11</td>
...
<td>test</td>
<td>blah24</td>
...
```

You didn't tell us what to do if `blah24` appears as part of a longer string or if you really wanted to specifically replace `unknown` or just whatever was within the tags or various other crucial details but hopefully you can figure all that out given the above.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.  `blah24` will be a unique ID in that html file.  I would like to specifically replace `unknown` which always appears above the unique ID and write the contents back out to the original file.

Comment: OK but can `blah241` or `fooblah24` also exist in the file? How about `foounknownbar`? If so, what would you want done with those? To write back to the original file with any UNIX command is `cmd file > tmp && mv tmp file`. GNU sed has a `-i` option and GNU awk has `-i inplace` but they both just do that same thing behind the scenes.

Comment: Nice, I came up with pretty much identical logic but in sed. +1 :)